# why recursive decent parser can not parse the aaaaaa EX(4.4.5) Ullman ravisethi

Tags: parsing, recursion, recursive-descent, recursive-backtracking

The grammar S -> a S a | a a generates all even-length strings of a's. We can devise a recursive-descent parser with backtrack for this
grammar. 
If we choose to expand by production S -> aa first, then we shall
only recognize the string aa. 
Thus, any reasonable recursive-descent parser will
try S -> aSa first.

Show that this recursive-descent parser recognizes inputs aa, aaaa, and
aaaaaaaa, but not aaaaaa.

Comment: Do a paper test and show where you get stuck.

Comment: on paper i can make it work but as it is asked in ullman aho, i wanted to know why it did not parse the string aaaaaa.

Answer (score 0):

The parser will try to invoke `match(a);S();match(a);` at first rather than `match(a);match(a);` as described in the problem. And note that as you try to recursively invoke`S()` inside the block `match(a);S();match(a);`, you have only invoked `match(a)` once, the 'a' symbol in the end is not consumed.

Answer (score 0):

I'll paraphrase myself from [this other answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/131772/81001).

It's actually a property of the "singleton match strategy" usual in naive implementations of recursive descent parsers with backtracking.

Quoting [this answer](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.compilers/c/Rr78g1zK6mE/m/EGcSu5YaK68J) by Dr Adrian Johnstone:

> The trick here is to realise that many backtracking parsers use what we call a singleton match strategy, in which as soon as the parse function for a rule finds a match, it returns. In general, parse functions need to return a set of putative matches. Just try working it through, and you'll see that a singelton match parser misses some of the possible derivations.

Also, the images available in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49465845/5915941) will help you visualize what's happening in the case you exemplified.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, the first condition for Recursive Decent Parser is that given grammar should not be Left Recursive and Non-deterministic. but here in question given grammar is **non-deterministic** so we need to convert that using left factoring and we'll get **S->aS', S'->Sa|a** and this will work I guess.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).