# A simple CFG claimed to have no equivalent PEG, that seems to have one anyway

Tags: grammar

In ["Packrat Parsing: a Practical Linear-Time Algorithm with Backtracking"](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/%7Ebaford/packrat/thesis/) on page 30 the author states that the context-free grammar (CFG):

```
S -> a S a | a S b | b S a | b S b | a
```

appears not to have a corresponding parsing expression grammar (PEG).

The above CFG is equivalent to:

```
S -> (a | b) S (a | b) | a
```

and can be summarized as "odd number of a's and b's with an 'a' in the middle". However the strait-forward translation of this to a PEG:

```
S <- (a / b) S (a / b) / a
```

seems to work fine and code for the same language.

[You can try this out yourself online using peg.js](https://pegjs.org/online) (enter the grammar as `S = ('a' / 'b') S ('a' / 'b') / 'a'`).

Is the author wrong or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just didn't test enough. Try inputs consisting of an odd number of `a`s. All match the grammar but PEG only accepts those of length 2<sup>*k*</sup>−1 for some integer *k*.

Comment: Thanks! It appears you are correct and length 5 is indeed the first odd number for which it fails, and then also for 9, 11, 13, but 7 and 15 work. Could you explain why the PEG only matches those specific lengths?

Comment: @hkBst: Not easily :-). The best way to try to understand it, in my opinion, is to grab a big block of paper and do the match by hand. It won't take *that* long. I did recently try to explain a very similar issue from exercise 4.4.5 in the Dragon book about recursive descent with backtracking. See https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/143480/dragon-book-4-4-5-exercise/143975, so that might be of some help. (If you have an earlier edition of the Dragon book, it's exercise 4.13.)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456994/how-does-backtracking-affect-the-language-recognized-by-a-parser